# How to load image in sama5d27-som1-ek kit using SDcard

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, sd-card, boot

I am following standard process to boot sama5d27-som1-ek kit using [SDcard](https://www.linux4sam.org/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d27Som1EKMainPage#Create_a_SD_card_with_the_demo) but i got following error

i cannot understand why it shows cannot open root device.i used 8GB sd for this process

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "mmcblk0p2" or unknown-block(179,2): error -30                         
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:                     
0100            8192 ram0                                                                           
 (driver?)                                                                                          
0101            8192 ram1                                                                           
 (driver?)                                                                                          
0102            8192 ram2                                                                           
 (driver?)                                                                                          
0103            8192 ram3                                                                           
 (driver?)                                                                                          
1f00              64 mtdblock0                                                                      
 (driver?)                                                                                          
1f01             640 mtdblock1                                                                      
 (driver?)                                                                                          
1f02              64 mtdblock2                                                                      
 (driver?)                                                                                          
1f03             128 mtdblock3                                                                      
 (driver?)                                                                                          
1f04            4096 mtdblock4                                                                      
 (driver?)                                                                                          
b300         7864320 mmcblk0                                                                        
 driver: mmcblk                                                                                     
  b301           65536 mmcblk0p1 da6e5492-01                                                        

  b302          914432 mmcblk0p2 da6e5492-02                                                        

Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)                    
CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper Not tainted 4.19.78-linux4sam-6.2 #1                                    
Hardware name: Atmel SAMA5                                                                          
Function entered at [<c010dcd8>] from [<c010ae5c>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c010ae5c>] from [<c0117f48>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0117f48>] from [<c0a01270>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0a01270>] from [<c0a01590>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0a01590>] from [<c0a01730>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0a01730>] from [<c0a00e1c>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0a00e1c>] from [<c0729e00>]                                                  
Function entered at [<c0729e00>] from [<c01010e8>]                                                  
Exception stack(0xc642dfb0 to 0xc642dff8)                                                           
dfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                       
dfc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000                       
dfe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000                                         
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2) ]---      
random: fast init done                                                                              
random: crng init done
```

please help to know error.because i am following standard process.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can not mount the rootfs. (can not find init)
Can you please show the kernel command line?
What file system do you use?
It looks like you have 2 partitions.

Comment: yes i have two partition,both are created automatically.i just selected image and sd card on etcher.one partition is fat32 and other is ext4

Comment: If we can assume the image you write with etcher is a good one, maybe you should try another SD card.

Comment: Do you have file system image present in mmcblk0p2 partition? Kernel unable to mount the rootfs.